# MVC how can i create (10)multiple textbox and have one parameter assign to those text box. I also want to pass the parameter to my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
public ActionResult Orders1(int order)
      {
                CostcoEntities1 context = new CostcoEntities1();

              var query = from   a in context.CM_Checkout_Details
                          where  a.CheckoutDetails_ID == order
                          select a;

                return View(query);
       }
```

Hello everyone!! I am new and need some help. I want to create 10 textbox to display the reference item details. The first textbox works fine however the second textbox states that the order parameter is null. I know this is a simple task and I am very new to MVC. Please help!!!I prefer to do this with html helper (if possible)

thank you in advance!!!

VIEW

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Orders1", "Track", FormMethod.Post))
{

   for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
   { 
      @i <input type="text" name="order" /><br />
   }   
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is going to be what you are looking for.  You can extend the htmlAttributes as needed.

```
 @model IEnumerable<TypeGoesHere>

    @foreach(var item in (IEnumerable<TypeGoesHere>)Model)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>item.SomeProperty, null,new {@name="order"})
        }
```